# WPF C#, method to change color depending on node's property value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

I have a hierarchial `TreeView` from an entity framework model.
My nodes all have a property "COID", checkout ID. I would like to display 3 different colors of rectangles depending on the value of the COID property.

```
 <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding tblLines}">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="2">
                                <Image Height="15" Margin="4" x:Name="imgTreeProject" Source="/DES STUDIO PR;component/Resources/Images/folder_closed.png"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin ="8" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                <Rectangle Name="X" Width="10" Height="10" Fill="Green"/>
                            </StackPanel>
```

Here is a converter I am trying to implement:

```
 public class CheckoutConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object entity, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var Baseentity = entity as TblBase;
        if (Baseentity.COID == MainWindow.LocalUser.ID)
        {
            return Colors.Green;
        }
        else if (Baseentity.COID == 0)
        {
            return Colors.Transparent;
        }
        else if (Baseentity.COID != 0)
        {
            return Colors.Black;
        }
        else
            return Colors.Purple;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

[image]

Comment: @Sudsy1002 Thank you. I have added some converter code I am trying to implement.

Comment: I'd suggest reading over Microsoft's [Data binding in depth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth) article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind the `Fill` property of the `Rectangle` to your data object

```
<Rectangle Name="X" Width="10" Height="10">
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <Binding Path=".">
            <Binding.Converter>
                <local:CheckoutConverter />
            </Binding.Converter>
        </Binding>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

...and return a `Brush` insetad of a `Color` from the converter:

```
public class CheckoutConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object entity, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var Baseentity = entity as TblBase;
        if (Baseentity.COID == MainWindow.LocalUser.ID)
        {
            return Brushes.Green;
        }
        else if (Baseentity.COID == 0)
        {
            return Brushes.Transparent;
        }
        else if (Baseentity.COID != 0)
        {
            return Brushes.Black;
        }
        else
            return Brushes.Purple;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: I missed that the op was returning colors instead of brushes. Good catch.

Comment: I have it exactly as you have it here. The Path set to "." creates an error :?

Comment: @mm8 Object reference is not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @mm8 I get that message popped up in the XAML. My treeview is a hierarchical dataset from an etity framework context.

Comment: I have added a picture to the original post, what does the "." do?

Comment: Can you build the app? "." bind to the current item, which is supposed to be a Baseentity object.

Comment: @mm8 I got it to work, thank you so much! The problem was that at startup something else was triggering the converter. I added a condition, which you can add to your solution:            if(entity is TblBase)